# Does a SQL connection close with "using" if the connection comes from a static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Am I closing my SQL connection correctly, by placing it inside a "using" block?

This is how I grab a new connection, execute a query, and return the results:

```
using (SqlConnection objCS = DB.LMSAdminConn())
{
    objCS.Open();
    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM users WHERE userid = @userid", objCS);
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userid;
    SqlDataReader reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //do something
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

The connection itself comes from this call:

```
public static SqlConnection LMSAdminConn()
{
    return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lmsadmin"].ToString());
}
```

I am opening the connection inside a "using" block, and I thought that the connection would be closed as well, because it is opened inside the "using" block. But since the "new SqlConnection" object is actually generated from an outside class, is my connection still getting appropriately closed? SQL Server shows the connection as still being open, but I'm not sure if that is ADO.NET connection pool recycling / sharing, or if the connection is truly being held open. I don't explicitly call .Close() on the connection inside the "using" block.

Do I need to explicitly close the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader objects as well, or are they disposed when we leave the "using" block as well?

Comment: The `using` statement does not know or care what the object "came from".  It will dispose its object.

Comment: They are closed and disposed when the `using` block terminates. You can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: Using statement will dispose your connection in the above case.

Comment: You should use `using` statements for (almost) all objects that implement `IDisposable` and that you're not maintaining references to in non-local variables. So yes, put your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`s in there too.

Answer (score 0):

A `using` block is essentially syntactic sugar for having a `try`/`finally` block that calls the `Dispose` method of the object it is acting on, it doesn't matter where that object was created.

For a `SqlConnection` object, calling `Dispose` will close the connection. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling `Close` or `Dispose`. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will close the connection once it loses scope. 
Sample:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
{
  sqlConn.Open();
  ...
}
```

This code will be converted into the following by the compiler :

```
try
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString");
    sqlConn.Open();
    ...
}
finally
{
   sqlConn.Close();
}
```

As you can see the **close()** is called in the **finally** block. 
This finally block will force close the connection even if there is an exception during run-time within the **using** block.

Comment: Your translation is wrong. The declaration and instantiation of the `sqlConn` variable is done before the `try` block begins, and the `finally` clause will not call `Close`, it will call `Dispose`. Please refer to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for a correct translation.

Answer (score 0):

You had an idea about `connection pools` - this is the right idea!

`ADO.NET` it is so beautiful that it tries to optimize everything and [store it in connection pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#removing-connections). But we still **need** to always **close connections**!